# Remove jerkiness effect from off-canvas bootstrap layout on mobile

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I'm using bootstrap's off-canvas layout from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/#). At the heart of it lies an animation effect for `right` css property which moves canvas to the left:

```
.row-offcanvas {
   right: 0;
   position: relative;
   transition: all .25s ease-out;
}

.row-offcanvas.active {
   right: 50%;
}
```

When viewed from PC browser the transition is smooth. However, when viewed from Android's Chrome browswer the transition is jerky. If you open [the link](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/#) from Android device (or perhaps from any mobile device) you'll see the effect.
What can I do to make it run smoothly on mobile browsers?

Comment: add -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;

Comment: See also [the bleeding-edge version of the example.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/examples/offcanvas/offcanvas.css)

Comment: @Christina, it doesn't do any good since Chrome uses `transition` property without vendor prefix.

Comment: @cvrebert, and how is it different to my approach?

Comment: It has the vendor-prefixed variants. I had assumed Christina had the right explanation.

Comment: @cvrebert, well, the solution offered by Christina didn't work :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `transform:translate` instead of `right`.

```
.row-offcanvas-navbar {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
  -o-transition: 300ms ease all;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.row-offcanvas-navbar.right.active {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-250px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-250px, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(-250px, 0);
  transform: translate(-250px, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
}
```